# mongodb does not push another object instead replaces the original object data

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py

I am making a warning system within discord.py and I got the actual data to write with the info I need, but when I run the command again it only replaces the data in the original object/warn. The point is that each warn is considered an object in the array, but it doesn't add another object for the new warn

```
 @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    # @commands.has_guild_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def warn(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
        if user is None:
            await ctx.send("You have not provided a user!")
            return

        if user is user.bot:
            await ctx.send(f"<@{ctx.author.id}, you cannot warn a bot!")
            return

        if user.id == ctx.author.id:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"<@{ctx.author.id}>, you are not allowed to warn yourself!")

            embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.guild.name} Custom Designed Bot")
            embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        reason = reason or None
        _id = await self.bot.warns.find_by_id({"_id": user.id})
        first_warning = True

        warn = {
            "_id": user.id,
            "guild": ctx.message.guild.id,
            "warn": [{
                "PunishType": 'warn',
                "Moderator": ctx.message.author.id,
                "Reason": reason,
            }]
        }
        if first_warning:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"<@{ctx.author.id}>, has warned <@{user.id}> for {reason}")

            embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await self.bot.warns.upsert(warn)
            return first_warning is False
        elif first_warning is False:
            warns = await self.bot.warns.find_by_id({"_id": user.id})["warns"]
            newwarn = [{
                "PunishType": "warn",
                "Moderator": ctx.author.id,
                "Reason": reason,
            }]
            warns.append(newwarn)
            await self.bot.warns.update(
                {"_id": "user.id"},
                {"$push": {"warns": warns}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array with pymongo.

You must get the database object like `await self.bot.warns.find_by_id({"_id": user.id})` get the array. Do `array.append(newwarn)` then insteadof updating `warn` with `newwarn` you replace `newwarn` with the array.

```py
 warn = {
            "_id": user.id,
            "guild": ctx.message.guild.id,
            "warns": [{
                "PunishType": 'warn',
                "Moderator": ctx.message.author.id,
                "Reason": reason,
            }]
        }

await self.bot.warns.upsert(warn)

warns = await self.bot.warns.find_by_id({"_id": user.id})["warns"]
newwarn = [{
            "PunishType": "warn",
            "Moderator": ctx.author.id,
            "Reason": reason,
}]
warns.append(newwarn)
await self.bot.warns.update(
                {"_id": "user.id"},
                { "$push" : {"warns": warns}})
```

Comment: I have inserted the code that you gave me, and it only still replaces it. I have updated my code with the whole command in case if anything could be obstructing it. the only thing is when I remove my if statements it comes up with coroutine object is not subscriptable on the warns = await

Comment: When you make your document with insert you need to have warns in it @Jango DarkWind

Comment: I don't understand i apologize

Comment: When you use insert_one to make the document you need to add `warns` in that object to make it @Jango DarkWind

Comment: I am not using insert_one anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227596/discussion-between-jango-darkwind-and-fluxedscript).